# Find all odd positive integers greater than 1 such that for any relatively prime divisors a and b of n, a+b-1 is also a divisor of n

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, integers, gcd-and-lcm

[image]

Somewhy I think that all such numbers are an empty set cuz a+b-1 is also odd, hence U can find some d: $d<n$, $d<a+b-1$, which is also odd, and relatively prime to $(a+b-1)=f$, and then again, f+d-1 must be a divisor of n, and so on, and so on, but at one step $f*+d*-1$ will be greater than n, hence contradiction..any thoughts?

Comment: All odd primes, maybe? (2 also works but q asks only for odd solutions.)

Comment: The empty set certainly is not the answer, since every prime satisfies that condition:

If $p$ is prime, then $\{a,b\}=\{1,p\}$ meaning that $a+b-1=p+1-1=p$ which is a divisor of $p$.

Comment: Prime powers like $3^3=27$.  One of the "relatively prime divisors" has to be $1$.

Comment: @5xum thanx. Any other solutions besides primes?

Comment: @OscarLanzi I guess $n=3^3=27$ will not work: it has no relatively prime divisors

Comment: Yes, it does; $(3, 1)=1$.

Comment: @Shaun I always forget about damn 1..

Comment: According to me it should have infinite solutions. Put b=1 and then a=n and hence we can generate infinite no. of solutions .Is not it??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Write $M = p^n m$, where $p$ is the smallest prime factor of $M$, and $(p^n,m) = 1$. Since $p^n$ is coprime to $m$, it is true that $p+m - 1 | M$. However, since $p+m-1$ is co-prime to $m$, as $p-1$ is co prime to $m$, because $m$ contains only prime factors greater than $p$, it follows that $p+m-1 \stackrel{(1)}{=} p^k$  for some $k$.

Now, again, $p^k + m - 1 = 2p^k - p$ is a divisor of $M$, which implies that $2p^{k-1} - 1$ is a divisor of $M$. However, since it is co prime to $p^k$, it will have to divide $m$. However, this implies that:
$$
2p^{k-1} - 1 | p (2p^{k-1}-1) - 2m = p-2
$$ by $(1)$.

This funny occasion occurs precisely when $k = 1$, since otherwise $2p^{k-1}-1 > p - 2$. If that happens, then of course $m=1$, and then $M = p^k$, where $p$ is a prime. You can check that it indeed holds true for prime powers, and hence the property holds true precisely for prime powers.

Comment: I guess U meant $gcd(p^n, m)$

Comment: Please would you explain why $2p^{k-1} - 1 \mid p (2p^{k-1}-1) - 2m = p-2$?

Comment: Nevermind: I see it now. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @NiHao92 It's common to write only $(a,b)$ for $\gcd\{a,b\}$ in discrete mathematics and number theory.

Comment: Thank you for the edits, @Shaun.

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: @TeresaLisbon thank you sooooo much for this answer, i was trying this problem for very long

Comment: @Aditya_math Oh , I answered this all those years ago! The key point is "the smallest prime dividing a number" is a great strategy in general.